# Simple Conv1D as first layer in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is my input

```
x_train.shape # (12, 7) 12 observations each of length 7
x_train # dtype('int32')
```

Here's the architecture I'd like to achieve:

[image]

I'd like a kernel of size 3 convolved over the sequence. From keras documentation at https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

"When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for sequences of 10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors, or (None, 128) for variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors."

Honestly I'm having a hard time understanding their logic. Here's my attempt

```
docs_sequence = Input(shape=(7,), dtype='float32') # Longest document is 7 words
convolution = Conv1D(filters = 1,  # only 1 convolution
                     kernel_size = 3, # tri grams
                     strides = 1,
                     input_shape = (1, 7),
                     padding = 'valid',
                     activation = 'relu')(docs_sequence)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(convolution)
cnn_model = Model(inputs = docs_sequence, outputs = [output])
cnn_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and I'm consistently getting

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_30: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: I've tried playing with the input shape, but again I'm having a hard time following their logic.

Comment: From the link you posted - Input shape 3D tensor with shape:  (batch_size, steps, input_dim). This could help you http://www.orbifold.net/default/2017/01/10/embedding-and-tokenizer-in-keras/ to tokenize your sentences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says, your input is two dimensional while the convolutional layer expects a three dimensional input.

With the following

```
docs_sequence = Input(shape=(7,1), ...
```

instead of

```
docs_sequence = Input(shape=(7,), ...
```

Keras accepts the model. Basically this adds a dimension of size one to the input (the three dimensions from the error message include the minibatch dimension which one can think of being prepended to the `shape` argument above).

`cnn_model.summary()` then gives:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 7, 1)              0
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 5, 1)              4
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 5, 1)              2
=================================================================
```

When preparing the actual input data, you may have to add this dimension of size one to your input data. You may want to use `numpy.atleast_2d()` or `numpy.atleast_3d()` for this, possibly combined with taking the transpose or use `numpy.expand_dims()`.

In your case, `np.atleast_3d(x_train)` gives a shape of `(12, 7, 1)`.